# Can I save current window position and buffer in register in VIM

Tags: vim

Sometimes, I split my VIM to 4 windows, and open different files in these windows. I want to know if I can save current scenario to a register, and get it back whenever I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save it into the file. You can read about it here: `:help mksession`

You also can use plugins to manage sessions, for instance, [session.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3150).

Right now i don't know how to save it to a register instead of file.

Answer (score 4):

There is no easy way to get the functionality you are looking for to be stored in a register, though there is built-in support for saving the current *session* to file.

```
:mks[ession][!] [file]
```

---

#### `:help mksession`

> Suppose you are editing along, and it is the end of the day.  You want
>   to quit work and pick up where you left off the next day.
>
> You can do
>   this by saving your editing session and restoring it the next day.
>   A Vim session contains all the information about what you are editing.
>
> This includes things such as the file list, window layout, global
>   variables, options and other information.

...

```
                                                  *:mks* *:mksession*
:mks[ession][!] [file]  Write a Vim script that restores the current editing
                        session.
                        When [!] is included an existing file is overwritten.
                        When [file] is omitted "Session.vim" is used.
```

---

#### Further documentation

- [Vim Documentation - usr_21 #sessions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.4)